# Positioning div to the center of the page

Tags: html, css, margin, centering

Hello I had problem positioning a div to the center of the page.

CSS:

```
.fancyClass{
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;  
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Also I should mention that this div is inside another div, so could that be a problem? How to avoid it than?

Comment: Try out http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: Your current solution will allow you to place the div to the center of the parent div, it's impossible to give further helpful details without context.

Comment: @PSL I need text to be aligned to the left...and it did not help.

Comment: @Nit here is the screenshot - http://yadi.sk/d/K_IGeq1gLDQ8h of how it looks. What info do you need?

Comment: Maybe because you haven't specified the width of your box? How wide is the direct parent element? Also: isn't the inline-block causing your box to hover to the left?

Comment: Please share details of the parent div as that will directly influence how the target div can be centered.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
margin-right:25%;
margin-left:25%;
```

Comment: There are some contact information aligned to the left: yadi.sk/d/K_IGeq1gLDQ8h And aligning text to center does not help

Comment: WOW thanks, this worked !!!!! YOU ARE MY SAVIOR. I have been trying to center this shit for over an hour. EDIT: cant understand why folk downvote you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enter the width to be smaller than the outer div?

Something like that:

```
.fancyClass{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto; <!-- that does the actual centering -->
#all the other attributes you have
}
```

Comment: @polyx add your outer div code, because it should work

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this and let us know

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outterDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv">
        some thing here
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outterDiv{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 25px;
}
.innerDiv{
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

***[fiddle EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/qYZ4y/)***

Answer (score 0):

here you can see the div is `horizontally` and `vertically` centered in page. Here is the ***[Demo](http://jsbin.com/jaqenusu/1/)***.

have a look at CSS.

```
body{margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
}

.fancyClass{
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

 <div class="fancyClass"> 
    this text will be center
  </div>
```